# How to create an object of proper type elegantly from the given input?

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, serialization, types

I get packets from the network that looks as follows in the following DTO form:

```
data class ContentElementField(
    val text: String? = null,
    val style: String? = null,
    val imagePath: String? = null,
    val caption: String? = null
)
```

The packet has the following invariant that specifies that either `text` and `style` or `imagePath` and `caption` are set together. One group excludes the other.

By following this invariant,

```
abstract class ContentElement

data class TextElement(val text: Text, val style: Style) : ContentElement()

data class ImageElement(val picturePath: Path, val caption: Text) : ContentElement()
```

either `TextElement` or `ImageElement` is created.

I abstain from writing a code as follows to implement this behavior:

```
if (isTextElementField(contentElementField)) createTextElement(contentElement.text, contentElement.style)

else if (isImageElementField(contentElementField)) createImageElement(contentElement.imagePath, contentElement.caption)
```

Because in the future, there will be more specific content elements to be added. This leads me to expand the branching above as more specific content elements are added.
I believe it can be implemented through polymorphism or double-dispatching through the visitor pattern.

What would you offer to solve this?